# How to see result of findByUsername delievered by CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

Need to see the search result of the:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {    
    public User findByUsername(String username);        
}
```

which I call from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody User findByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String userName) {
    return usersRepo.findByUsername(userName);
}
```

The method above is called via:

```
@GET("/users/find")
public User findByUsername(String userName);
```

And the class User is here:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;    

    private String username;
    etc...
```

Results of the default methods I can see in my browser by typing e.g. localhost:8080/users

I tried many possible requests but it seems that I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly u need?

Comment: I want to see the result of findByUsername in a web browser. Which address should I call in the web browser? I tried:localhost:8080/users/find?Username99

Comment: try this
localhost:8080/users/find?username=99

Comment: You want to return User Object in response body so in browser u will get Object.

Comment: May be this is too naive but what is this concept? How can we call an interface's method with interface's object? I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Here you will get plane User object on browser so try to change return type to String.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User findByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    return usersRepo.findByUsername(username);
}
```

Hit this URL from local machine

> localhost:8080/users/find?username=99

Comment: What I needed was localhost:8080/users/find?username=Username99 and you helped me to figure it out. Good man!

Answer (score 1):

Now I recognize that my question was about testing an API. The best solution for it is to use [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/). The tool is really easy to learn and request results are in a better form.

Comment: Hey you can use DHC also for testing API's..check out this 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm